# How to convert a vector<int> to string in C++

Tags: c++, string, vector, iterator, ostream

Suppose I have a `vector<int>` and I want to convert it into string, what should I do?
What I got from searching on the internet is

```
std::ostringstream oss;

if (!vec.empty())
{
  // Convert all but the last element to avoid a trailing ","
 std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end()-1,
    std::ostream_iterator<int>(oss, ","));

// Now add the last element with no delimiter
oss << vec.back();
}
```

But I cannot understand what it means or how it works. Is there any other simple to understand way?

Comment: What specifically do you not understand about how it works?

Comment: I don't get what this statement does `std::copy(vec.begin(), vec.end()-1, std::ostream_iterator<int>(oss, ","));`

Comment: can someone please suggest any other way to do it?

Comment: @ronilp there's no need for another way, this one works fine, `std::copy` is the most readable and idiomatic way to copy things. "I don't understand it" is not a reason to switch implementations. You'll need to **read the documentation.**

Comment: the way 0x499602D2 suggested is much more easier to understand. I was looking for such a way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code is only needed if you want to add a delimiter after every inserted integer, but even then it doesn't have to be that complicated. A simple loop and the use of `to_string` is far more readable:

```c++
std::string str;

for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); ++i) {
    str += std::to_string(vec[i]);
    if (i+1 != vec.size()) { // if the next iteration isn't the last
        str += ", "; // add a comma (optional)
    }
}
```

Comment: suppose no comma was required then, `str += ""` would be the change, right?

Comment: @ronilp Then you wouldn't need the `if` statement at all, just the `str += to_string(vec[i])` part.

Answer (score 0):

Delimiting to numbers,

```
std::vector<int> v {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
std::string s("");
for(auto i : v)
    s += std::to_string(i);
```

With a comma seperator

```
std::vector<int> v {0, 1, 2, 3, 4};
std::string s("");
for(auto i : v)
    s += std::to_string(i) + ",";
s.pop_back();
```